# How to speed up for loop/append to vector in R

Tags: r

I have ~11,000,000 rows in a data frame, i need to loop through each, do a small calculation and then retrieve the corresponding p-value from a chi-squared distribution using pchisq(). Every time this value is retrieved it is appended to an empty vector which is later on added to the data frame.

This code is very inefficient and took exactly a week to run on the server, i believe that is due to the append() function having to copy the whole vector every time. How can i make this as efficient as possible?

Here is the current loop:

```
std_err <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(father)){
  std_err <- append(std_err, pchisq((mother[i,7]-father[i,7])^2/((mother[i,8])^2 + (father[i,8])^2), df=1, lower.tail = F))
}


father[ ,"p_std_err"] <- std_err
write.table(father, "father+standard_error.sumstats", sep = '\t', col.names = T, row.names = F, quote = F)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of your data structure? It would help me in a similar problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pchisq()` is vectorized, so you don't need a loop at all. You can just write:

```
pchisq((mother[, 7] - father[, 7])^2 / (mother[, 8]^2 + father[, 8]^2), df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! So i can just assign that block there to a variable and it will make the vector without having to loop through anything? how much faster would you expect this to be?

Comment: Yup, you can just assign that to `std_err`. I tested with a vector of 100,000 and it's 460 times faster there. I would expect the difference to be quite a big bigger still for a larger vector.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't just test the vectorized code on it's own in the first place: `pchisq()` on a vector of 10 million (which is what your problem boils down to) takes 5 seconds on my machine.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila, would you mind adding the data setup for testing in your answer? I for one would be interested in reproducing this.

Comment: yep it went from nearly a week to 3-5 seconds of compute time. I am absolutely astounded and cant thank you enough for pointing this out!

Comment: @chriswills glad it worked out! Vectorized code is always much faster than loops.

Comment: @larsoevlisen I just replaced the test statistic with `rexp(1e7)` for testing, i.e. I ran: `x <- rexp(1e7); bench::mark(pchisq(x, 1))`. For larger data it might be worth creating more vectors and performing the calculation as well, but here the time is negligible.